# Python3.6.2 why is Decimal(x) != Decimal(str(x))

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, python-3.6

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal(6.49)
```

> Decimal('6.4900000000000002131628207280300557613372802734375')

```
Decimal("6.49")
```

> Decimal('6.49')

Umm, why would these be different? Is this a bug in the `Decimal` library? Or is this indeed desired behavior? If so, why?

Comment: 6.4900000000000002131628207280300557613372802734375 is the exact value of the float you used.

Comment: I understand how floating point numbers work, and when I asked the question it wasn't obvious to me what the problem was. But coming back to it today, it's now obvious to me. `Decimal(6.49)` is creating a decimal out of the float number `6.490000...213...`, whereas `Decimal('6.49')` is creating a decimal straight from the string, without converting it to a float first.